# Travelling to Malta

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am the non-EU spouse of an EEA national and traveling to Malta for holidays without my husband. Will I go through immigration controls at the UK border when returning to the UK, even though I have my mariage certificate and residence card issued by UK authorities?

Comment: Yes, since you'll be arriving from outside Common Travel Area.

Answer (score 2):

All travel from outside the common travel area goes through immigration. You will show your passport, resident permit and have your finger prints scanned. Unless you've joined the [Registered Traveller Service](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller), you should go down the none UK/EEA channels.